# Bootstrap Datatable Search Filter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap datatable has a search functionality (obviously) but i'm having a trouble at some case. All the strings included in the table will be searched even the values inside buttons.

How can i exclude the buttons from the search functionality or can I exclude a column in search?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `searchable` to `false` on those columns you don't want to search within. Reference: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchable